# code for finding biggest factor of the number

Tags: c#

I'm improving my C#  skills and now I'm writing code for finding biggest factor of the number. However, it doesn't display anything

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int64 a = 600851475143;
    List<Int64> dividers = new List<Int64>();
    for (Int64 b = 2; b < a; b++)
    {
        if (a % b == 0)
        {
            dividers.Add(b);
        }
    }
    Int64 max = dividers.Max();
    Console.WriteLine(max);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: try setting a breakpoint at the `Console.WriteLine(max);` line and see if `dividers` has any values, as well as `max`. Also, you can stop your loop at `b < a / 2` because anything over half of the value isn't going to divide into `a`.

Comment: Your program works fine - it just takes a *really* long time to execute. You need to find a more efficient means of doing this.

Comment: To be more efficient, you may limit your loop to sqrt(a). In that case, every time you find a divider x, also store in dividers y = a/x

Comment: ...taking the other comments into consideration as well, wouldn't it be faster to iterate backwards and stop on your first find?  Unless you need all the factors as well?

Comment: @dub i tried with breakpoints, but it still doesn't displays. Also, dividers doesn't have any values.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine - it just takes a *really* long time to execute. You need to find a more efficient means of doing this.

A trick you can use is to only factor up to the square root - factors always come in pairs.

```
Int64 a = 600851475143;
List<Int64> dividers = new List<Int64>();
for (Int64 b = 2; b <= Math.Sqrt(a); b++)
{
    if (a % b == 0)
    {
        dividers.Add(b);
        dividers.Add(a / b);
    }
}
Int64 max = dividers.Max();
```

You can further improve this - you can instead of keeping a list of all of the factors, just keep track of the biggest one seen so far.

Comment: A better trick could be to say `if (a % b == 0)
    {
        dividers.Add(b);
        a /= b; }`. This would only give the _prime_ divisors of the original number, though. However, it is not hard to see how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing now that you're trying to solve [Euler Problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) I'm not going to give a direct answer.

Things to consider when solving this problem:

**## 1 ##**
You only have to check up to the sqrt() of that number.

```
double limit = Math.Sqrt(number);
for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
```

**## 2 ##** An IsPrime function

```
public static bool IsPrime(long number)
{
    if ((number & 1) == 0)
    {
        return number == 2;
    }

    double limit = Math.Sqrt(number);
    for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2)
    {
        if ((number % i) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return number != 1;
}
```

**## 3 ##**
When you find a factor `(a % b == 0)`, check if b or (a/b) are prime and keep the largest one that exceeds the currently known largest prime factor

Comment: Thank you @Shar1er80 This is just part of a problem. I was just solving eulers project problem which is The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

Comment: @BGA Ahh! Good ole Euler projects.  Well, I don't want to just provide the asnwer to you, but you should have what you need to solve Euler Problem 3 now.  Primarily, the prime check algorithm that you would use to check if the found factors (b & a/b) are prime.